# Processing multiple collections based on the same base type

Tags: c#, refactoring, covariance, open-closed-principle

I have a series of collections of types, all of which are derived from the same base class, and a set of predicates for searching for each one , e.g.

```
public abstract class Animal { ... }    
public class Dog : Animal { ... }       
public class Cat : Animal { ... }

...
Func<Dog, bool> DogFinder = ...;
Func<Cat, bool> CatFinder = ...;
...

List<Dog> Dogs = GetDogs(DogFinder);
List<Cat> Cats = GetCats(CatFinder);
```

Is there a way that I can work this to avoid the repetition for each type?

My next step is to take the Dogs, Cats, and convert to a common 'Result' type and return a collection of these which is fairly straightforward, but I feel as though the repetition in the middle should be factored out so that as I add more types of Animal going forward it will scale cleanly.

Comment: Have you given any thought to using interfaces? It'd allow you to do something like `GetAnimal(IAnimal animal)`, and thus reducing code redundancy across the board.

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics to eliminate some of the repetition, e.g.:

```
List<TAnimal> GetAnimals<TAnimal>(Func<TAnimal, bool> predicate) : where TAnimal : Animal
{
  ...
}
```

Then you could just call like this:

```
List<Dog> Dogs = GetAnimals(DogFinder);
List<Cat> Cats = GetAnimals(CatFinder);
```

You could also overload the method (and predicate) to take two in params and return a list of your base type, like this:

```
List<Animal> GetAnimals(Func<TAnimal1, TAnimal2, bool> predicate) 
    : where TAnimal1 : Animal
    : where TAnimal2 : Animal
{
   ...
}
```

Then you could get your dogs and cats together w/ a new predicate:

```
Func<Dog, Cat, bool> DogAndCatFinder = ...;
```

And get your list like this:

```
List<Animal> DogsAndCats = GetAnimals(DogAndCatFinder);
```